# C# Table Per Hierarchy Projection Union

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, union, table-per-hierarchy

I'm using table per hierarchy to project to model classes. When I use of type in Linq to Entities, all of my results are always the last type which was projected. What I mean is if I have these for domain models:

```
public interface IPerson { string Name {get;set;} }
public abstract class Person : IPerson { public string Name { get;set; } }
public class Employee : Person{ }
public class Manager : Person { }
```

And I have a Person table with a Name and type column, and use table per hierarchy to yield me specific Entities (which I'll refer to as EmployeeEntity and ManagerEntity).

When I use this code:

```
IQueryable<IPerson> people = entities.OfType<ManagerEntity>().Select(x => new Manager 
{ Name = x.name }).Concat(entities.OfType<EmployeeEntity>().Select(y => new Employee
{ Name = y.name }));

var projectedPeople = people.ToList();
```

All of the types of objects in projectedPeople are Employee, even the the objects that should be of type Manager. If I remove the Concat call and run them individually, I get the correct type back (Manager or Employee).

What am I doing wrong here? I wrote some test code that removed Linq from the equation by making dummy lists of objects and calling AsQueryable on them, followed by a projection, and that worked as it should.

Comment: I just noticed that if I bring the objects into memory by doing this `IQueryable<IPerson> people = entities.OfType<ManagerEntity>().Select(x => new Manager 
{ Name = x.name })ToList().Concat(entities.OfType<EmployeeEntity>().Select(y => new Employee
{ Name = y.name }).ToList());` it returns the appropriate types. Bringing everything into memory at this point isn't a solution for me though.